# How to binding data to and register property in user controls WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, user-controls, windows-phone-8

I have a user controls:

```
<UserControl>
<Grid Name="grid1" Background="#1133CC" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Width="200" Height="200">

        <Image Name="img1" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title"}/>
    </Grid>
</UserControls>
```

Title: string
ImageSource: BitmapImage

How to use binding data in MainPage.xaml like:

```
<Grid>
<local:myUserControl Title="{Binding Title"} ImageSoure="{Binding ImageSource}" />
</Grid>
```

How to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're basically asking "How do I do binding". A good read is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852595.aspx and nearly any other Binding resource you find out there.

In your case you will need an object that has a `Title` and a `ImageSource` property that is set as the `DataContext` of the control (or one of its parents like the `PhoneApplicationPage`). You can set the `DataContext` from your code behind (or in XAML) (if you're on the Page then you can simple set `DataContext = ...`.